# google maps onclick go to marker on map

Tags: google-maps

I'm having issues trying to get my map to go to the marker of a location when a "View on Map" link is clicked. I keep getting the error "TypeError: map.setOptions is not a function".

Here's the code:

```
var infowindow = null;
function initialize(){
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:3,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),myOptions);
    setMarkers(map,sites);
  }
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'Loading...'
  });
  var sites = [
    ['GIC Campers Sydney',-33.935477,151.012108,1,'xxx'],
    ['GIC Campers Brisbane',-27.5445735,153.0139405,1,'yyy'],
    ['GIC Campers Melbourne',-37.650735,144.940551,1,'zzz']
  ];
  function setMarkers(map,markers){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/templates/home/images/google-pin.png',
      new google.maps.Size(60,60),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(30,60));
    for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
      var sites = markers[i];
      var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1],sites[2]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:siteLatLng,
        map:map,
        icon:image,
        title:sites[0],
        zIndex:sites[3],
        html:sites[4]
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map,this);
      });
    bounds.extend(siteLatLng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
};
function loadcity(which){
  initialize();
  if(which == 'gic-campers-sydney'){
    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.935477,151.012108);
    map.setOptions({center:newPos,zoom:15});
  }
  if(which == 'gic-campers-brisbane'){
    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.5445735,153.0139405);
    map.setOptions({center:newPos,zoom:15});
  }
  if(which == 'gic-campers-melbourne'){
    var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.650735,144.940551);
    map.setOptions({center:newPos,zoom:15});
  }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  initialize();
  jQuery('.updatemap').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

and an example link:

```
<a onclick="loadcity('gic-campers-brisbane');" class="updatemap" href="#gic-campers-brisbane">View on map</a>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map variable is local to the initialize function.  It is not available inside the loadcity function.

One fix is to make it global (like your infowindow):

```
var infowindow = null;
var map = null;
function initialize(){
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:3,
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'),myOptions);
    setMarkers(map,sites);
  }
```

Not sure why you recreate the map (call initialize() every time loadcity runs), you really should only need to do that once.

Comment: ok wow, i'm feeling real intelligent now haha thanks so much for your help, that worked.